# What setting to (ab)use node.js as a super quick polling and ajax server for updating database (similar to Google Spreadsheet approach)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, node.js, stream

I hope that my title is not too long.

Simple question/title:

What setting should I use to **(Ab)Use node.js as a super quick polling and ajax server for updating and double-checking client/server-side changes instantly?** 
--> (similar to Google's approach of dealing with multiple people updating multiple stuff within a particular spreadsheet).

I haven't used node.js yet but did some reading and watching videos in the past and guess it's the (at the moment) right choice for doing what I'm about to do (see title/above).

So think of it as a house I'm trying to build but need the most stable right base which is not gonna break after making the house a whole castle....

So following Code Example:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('request received');
}).listen(9000);
```

Regards the 'http': Is there a 'spdy' or even better parameter i can use to realise the goal of building (potentially) better even than the Google Spreadsheet or at least as good? Asumed my Server is awesome and so on....

Thanks

Norbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into [ShareJS](http://sharejs.org/). It handles concurrent editing of plain text and arbitrary json data.

Comment: So you are saying I should make use of node.js in combination with ShareJS, rather than just simple jQuery Ajax.on(...) calls? Is ShareJS instead of $.ajax then?

Comment: ShareJS handles a lot more than just the connections to the server, it also handles the operational transforms and other things needed for concurrent editing. Also, ShareJS is a node.js module available on npm, so it's something you can easily incorporate into your node.js application.

Comment: Thanks mscdex, that sounds very reasonable to me. So you say I can just use composer to drop it next to my node.js?

Comment: Typically you would install ShareJS via npm (`npm install sharejs`) and then require() it in your node.js application and use it according to the ShareJS documentation.

Comment: Cool, is there any version your recommend me to make use of without running into mature bugs? Like ShareJs 0.7 or something...

Comment: I haven't used it myself yet, so I would either follow what the readme says or ask the maintainer about the current status.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing. I think i've understood something wrong according to the node.js part. Can I use composer to install node.js for my Zend Studio Workspace or ... is that a separate question? confused

Comment: node.js is separate software. You can obtain the latest (stable) version from nodejs.org. Pre-built binaries for various platforms as well as the source code (if you want to build yourself) can be found there.